# Sql command doesn't work correctly in visual studio - oracle

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, vb.net, oracle

I want to execute this command:

```
SELECT        
    WORKORDERID, 
    (SELECT WORKTYPEID FROM WORK_TYPE v WHERE v.WORKTYPEID = e.WORKTYPE) w
FROM            
    WORKORDERS e
```

It works in SQL Server and Visual Studio but when I want to execute this command on the oracle (I have same table in oracle and SQL Server) by Visual Studio Server Explorer I got this error:

> Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'SELECT'.
>   Error in SELECT clause: expression near 'FROM'.
>   Missing FROM clause. Unable to parse query text.

And after that show data correctly but it doesn't work in dataset

Comment: I know TSQL, but I know enough about Oracle to know the sysntax isn't identical so maybe your query just isn't valid in pSql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant specify another select query inside the columns to be selected. Try using "Join" instead.

```
select e.WORKORDERID, v.WORKTYPEID 
from WORKORDERS e
join WORK_TYPE v on v.WORKTYPEID =e.WORKTYPE
```

This should work.

Comment: Of course you can if the subquery returns one row. @BenRobinson exactly the same like in Oracle. There must be something else wrong with author's query. Check this SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48569/2

Comment: Yes that is totally valid. Oracle doesn't like extra carriage returns though.